# Crash report of process (another activity) inside Wrapper Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, process, crash

I have a wrapper Activity name {Foo} which has a list of games. Then I click the icon of game and over {Foo} I start another Activity name FooFaa. For the sake of allotting it more RAM I made it another process.

Now, I am playing FooFaa and suddenly it crashes due to some Exception. So this activity crashes and process is also killed. Now what I see is the {Foo} activity. But inside the whole game there would have been that exception in one of hundred of these functions or may be due to some variable.

I wish to catch that exception from the parent class {Foo} and dump it in a File. The dumping part is fine. But how to catch that exception.

Inside Foo when FooFaa is started [startActivity(FooFaaintent)]. There the exception handling won't help. So anyone to guide.

Thanks.